# Filtering Outliers - how to make median-based Hampel Function faster?

Tags: python, function, pandas, filter

I need to use a Hampel filter on my data, stripping outliers.

I haven't been able to find an existing one in Python; only in Matlab and R.

[Matlab function description][1]

[Stats Exchange discussion of Matlab Hampel function][2]

[R pracma package vignette; contains hampel function][3]

I've written the following function, modeling it off the function in the R pracma package; however, it is far far slower than the Matlab version. This is not ideal; would appreciate input on how to speed it up.

The function is shown below-

```
def hampel(x,k, t0=3):
    '''adapted from hampel function in R package pracma
    x= 1-d numpy array of numbers to be filtered
    k= number of items in window/2 (# forward and backward wanted to capture in median filter)
    t0= number of standard deviations to use; 3 is default
    '''
    n = len(x)
    y = x #y is the corrected series
    L = 1.4826
    for i in range((k + 1),(n - k)):
        if np.isnan(x[(i - k):(i + k+1)]).all():
            continue
        x0 = np.nanmedian(x[(i - k):(i + k+1)])
        S0 = L * np.nanmedian(np.abs(x[(i - k):(i + k+1)] - x0))
        if (np.abs(x[i] - x0) > t0 * S0):
            y[i] = x0
    return(y)
```

The R implementation in "pracma" package, which I am using as a model:

```
function (x, k, t0 = 3) 
{
    n <- length(x)
    y <- x
    ind <- c()
    L <- 1.4826
    for (i in (k + 1):(n - k)) {
        x0 <- median(x[(i - k):(i + k)])
        S0 <- L * median(abs(x[(i - k):(i + k)] - x0))
        if (abs(x[i] - x0) > t0 * S0) {
            y[i] <- x0
            ind <- c(ind, i)
        }
    }
    list(y = y, ind = ind)
}
```

Any help in making function more efficient, or a pointer to an existing implementation in an existing Python module would be much appreciated. Example data below; %%timeit cell magic in Jupyter indicates it currently takes 15 seconds to run:

```
vals=np.random.randn(250000)
vals[3000]=100
vals[200]=-9000
vals[-300]=8922273
%%timeit
hampel(vals, k=6)
```

[1]: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/hampel.html   [2]: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26552/what-is-a-hampel-filter-and-how-does-it-work [3]: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/pracma.pdf

Comment: Thanks @EHB for the implementation. I have used it and it really worked for me in most cases. But I found it failed to find spikes if they are at the end of the time series. Is there any way to modify the filter to find the spikes if they are at the end?

Comment: @ Lufy, maybe just eliminate the last few measurements in your series if they're not strictly needed? If you find a good answer add it here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Pandas solution is several orders of magnitude faster:

```
def hampel(vals_orig, k=7, t0=3):
    '''
    vals: pandas series of values from which to remove outliers
    k: size of window (including the sample; 7 is equal to 3 on either side of value)
    '''
    #Make copy so original not edited
    vals=vals_orig.copy()    
    #Hampel Filter
    L= 1.4826
    rolling_median=vals.rolling(k).median()
    difference=np.abs(rolling_median-vals)
    median_abs_deviation=difference.rolling(k).median()
    threshold= t0 *L * median_abs_deviation
    outlier_idx=difference>threshold
    vals[outlier_idx]=np.nan
    return(vals)
```

Timing this gives 11 ms vs 15 seconds; vast improvement.

I found a solution for a similar filter in [this post.](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2015/03/16/outlier_detection/)

Comment: I agree with @EduardoOsorio this implementation is nor correct. You should edit the calculation of `median_abs_deviation` in your solution.

Comment: At first glance I thought the solution by Eduardo and yours are equivalent, but actually this has a subtle error. It's best to verify by doing a tiny example by hand.

Answer (score 9):

Solution by @EHB above is helpful, but it is incorrect. Specifically, the rolling median calculated in *median_abs_deviation* is of *difference*, which itself is the difference between each data point and the rolling median calculated in *rolling_median*, but it should be the median of differences between the data in the rolling window and the median over the window. I took the code above and modified it:

```
def hampel(vals_orig, k=7, t0=3):
    '''
    vals: pandas series of values from which to remove outliers
    k: size of window (including the sample; 7 is equal to 3 on either side of value)
    '''
    
    #Make copy so original not edited
    vals = vals_orig.copy()
    
    #Hampel Filter
    L = 1.4826
    rolling_median = vals.rolling(window=k, center=True).median()
    MAD = lambda x: np.median(np.abs(x - np.median(x)))
    rolling_MAD = vals.rolling(window=k, center=True).apply(MAD)
    threshold = t0 * L * rolling_MAD
    difference = np.abs(vals - rolling_median)
    
    '''
    Perhaps a condition should be added here in the case that the threshold value
    is 0.0; maybe do not mark as outlier. MAD may be 0.0 without the original values
    being equal. See differences between MAD vs SDV.
    '''
    
    outlier_idx = difference > threshold
    vals[outlier_idx] = rolling_median[outlier_idx] 
    return(vals)
```

Comment: @RachelCyr, in this case, L stands for the scale factor for Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The OP was using numpy and others likely will be too, so a numpy solution might be handy. A few notes, I don't scale the threshold (it is a linear scale, why bother) and I don't fill bad values, I return the indices of bad values. Could easily be modified to change those, but the idea is there:

```
import numpy as np
def hampel_filter_v(data, half_win_length, threshold):
    padded_data = np.concatenate(
        [[np.nan]*half_win_length, data, [np.nan]*half_win_length])
    windows = np.ma.array(
        np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(padded_data, 2*50+1))
    windows[np.isnan(windows)] = np.ma.masked
    median = np.ma.median(windows, axis=1)
    mad = np.ma.median(np.abs(windows-np.atleast_2d(median).T), axis=1)
    bad = np.abs(data-median) > (mad*threshold)
    return np.where(bad)[0]
```